# Equation with 3D matrix

Tags: matrix, 3d, formula, octave, operation

I want to solve an equation in which two matrix with different sizes are part of it:

```
n(s,t)
Reafd(s,c)
```

My intention is to create a 3D matrix in which I can store every possible value calculated with the formula, but I keep having this error message.

```
warning: division by zero
warning: called from
    pres_drop at line 38 column 19

V=1; 
Reaf=zeros(s,t,size(c)) %calculation of Reaf
vair=kvisc(Tamb);

for i=1:s
   for j=1:t
     for k=1:length(c)
  Reaf(i,j,k)= sqrt((11.8336*V/(L.*n(i,j).*vair))+(Reafd(i,k)).^2); %<-line 38, column 19 after the first k
    
endfor
 
endfor

endfor 
 
 endfunction
```

Can someone please help me?

Comment: From the message it appears either L or n(I,j) are zero valued for one of the iterations.

Comment: Have you examined the variable values when the error occurs? Without an example of your data that causes the error, it's impossible for us to say for sure which value is causing it.